# Print specific range of numbers in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I'm trying to teach my self programming. I am currently studying python.
My resource is MIT OCW

I've just learnt lists and would like to print out the 5th to 9th number in a range (0,10)

The code I've written so far is

```
new_list = range (0,10)
for i in range (0,10) 
    print "numbers are", new_list [5:9]
```

I'm getting a Syntax error when I run the code in shell. Error is pointed to the brackets when I use both square and normal brackets.

Anyone can assist me get the desired output?

Also, is that the right use of the "for" function?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Hey, I did format it, but the preview window didn't outlay the code as I'd written it in the editor.

Comment: I'm posting from phone, anyway to improve on this?

Comment: did you put  `:` at the end of `for` loop statement?

Comment: Hey Salman, I hadn't put the full colon.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Once again with Python, simplicity reigns supreme. Give this a shot, let me know how it goes:

```
print([*range(0,10)])
```

Answer (score 4):

It is simple:

```
print(my_list[5:9])
```

Answer (score -1):

Following your input, I finally have this code

```
for i in range (0,10)[5:9]:


(indentation) print "the numbers are", i
```

Answer (score -2):

You can print the 5th through 9th value by using a for-loop with initial value 5 and final value 9

```
for i in range(5, 9):
    print new_list[i]
```

This is provided you 'want' to use a for-loop rather than outputting them directly using:

`print new_list[5:9]`

Comment: While this is true, I wanted to pick certain numbers in a longer range of numbers. Next I want to try output numbers completely divisible by 5 in a range of 0,100

Answer (score -2):

As stated also by others, there is 1 approach which someone achieved already (in answers), and 2 which uses loop to print result:

How about code like this:

```
new_list = range (0,10)

for element in new_list[5:9]:
  print "numbers are", element
```

Comment: I've run this on the compiler and output on shell looks wonderful. I like it.  What's the difference between what I posted and your code? What's the use of "i"?

Comment: Your code is primarily missing a colon ":" after a loop statement.
Furthermore, you either need a loop for printing values 1 at a time (my code), or all elements without a loop, as others has written.

Comment: Alright. So either have it as a loop. Or not.  I've re-written the code following your advise and combining a technique I've seen here new code is "for i in range (0,10): print" numbers are ", i[5:9]

Answer (score -2):

I've seen my mistake. The full colon after the "for" function.

Code now is:

```
new_list = range (0,10)
for i in range (0,10):
  print "the numbers are", new_list [5:9]
```

The outcome is

`the numbers are [5,6,7,8]`

Thanks.