# how can i print a range of numbers without a list in python?

Tags: python

```
for make in range(1, content+1):
    print(make)
```

Result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

But i want them like this :

1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Comment: Hint: `end=` on your `print`

Comment: Just `print(*range(1, content+1))` would do it

Comment: print(make, end='') it works perfectly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41523396/print-specific-range-of-numbers-in-a-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the print command to tell it the separator to use with the "end" argument:

```py
for make in range(1, content+1):
    print(make,end=' ')
```